# Allow space before heading at top of page in book class

Tags: spacing, sectioning

[Another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103737/retain-space-before-section-heading-in-memoir-class-at-top-of-page) asks about the possibility of leaving space before a section heading at the top of a page in the memoir class. Is there a similar solution for the book class?

One workaround I've considered is to redefine `\section` using the following:

```
% If no page break, add a baseline skip to counteract following one
\vspace{\baselineskip}

% Take away a baseline skip. This is because an extra line
% is automatically added if the section heading is at the
% beginning of a page
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}

% Allow for some space before the heading, so that the page
% is filled properly
\vspace*{0pt plus 8pt}
```

This works for the most part, but adds an extra line of space in certain situations which don't seem to be reproducible in a minimal example.

I’m using LuaLaTex, so answers making use of lua scripts are acceptable.

A minimal example would be fairly generic, except that I'm using the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass[openany,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\clubpenalty=0
\brokenpenalty=0
\interlinepenalty=0
\widowpenalty=3000

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{12pt plus 8pt minus 4pt}{6pt}

\flushbottom

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\section{Two}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

As to why I would want to do this: it’s for grid typography; I’d rather have blank space at the top of the page than misalign the rest of the text block.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You want to introduce a page break and leave additionaly space before the section heading (i.e. the title?) starts?

Comment: I don't actually want to force a page break. (I've removed that line of code as irrelevant.)

Comment: Well, it's just some additional space (a fixed amount?) before the heading?

Comment: I want to add something like 0pt plus 4pt. The purpose is to allow a flush bottom margin without introducing extra space between lines or paragraphs.

Comment: It's a flexible amount of additional space when the heading happens to be at the top of a page. The flexible amount of space when the heading is _not_ at the top of a page works fine with the `titlesec` package.

Comment: flexible space such as `plus 8pt minus 4pt` is bound to push you off the grid (if it stretches or shrinks at all)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not necessarily, I think. If parskip baselineskip are not flexible, it should keep you on the grid. In fact, if other flexible space makes it on the page, the stretch may allow the text blocks to stay on the grid. This all assumes we only care about body text being on a grid, not section titles.

Comment: If that is the only stretch space on the page I suppose it could push everything else to the bottom (so grid aligned) but \fill would be easier for that, if there is any other stretch on the page and so teh shortfall is shared between glue items all text will be off grid